# Extremely inefficient python code

Tags: python, geometry

I have made a program to allow users to input the largest possible hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle and my program will list down a list of  all possible sides of the triangles. Problem is, the program takes forever to run when I input a value such as 10000. Any suggestions on how to improve the efficiency of the program?

Code:

```
largest=0
sets=0
hypotenuse=int(input("Please enter the length of the longest side of the triangle"))
for x in range(3,hypotenuse):
    for y in range(4, hypotenuse):
        for z in range(5,hypotenuse):
            if(x<y<z):                   
                 if(x**2+y**2==z**2):
                     commonFactor=False
                     for w in range(2,x//2):
                         if (x%w==0 and y%w==0 and z%w==0):
                             commonFactor=True
                             break
                     if not(commonFactor):
                         print(x,y,z)
                         if(z>largest):
                             largest=z
                         sets+=1
print("Number of sets: %d"%sets)
print("Largest hypotenuse is %d"%largest)
```

Thanks!

Comment: In Big O notation, your code is terrible, its like `n^4`, you are using way too many for loops you have to be smart about that.

Comment: Sounds like an ideal opportunity to play with [profiling!](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

Comment: "the largest possible hypotenuse" and "list down a list of all possible sides of the triangles" Are my math totally wrong or is there really an infinite number of right-angled triangle having a hypotenuse < X  (as there is an infinite number of values in the range (0,X) ... )

Comment: @sylvain: assuming he is looking for stuff like 3**2+4**2=5**2  edit: damn you were 33sec faster to realize your mistake ;-)

Comment: Oups. How silly am I, *integers* :/

Comment: What's the `commonFactor` filtering about?

Comment: did my solution give you what you wanted? (if not, what do you want more?, if yes, can you select an answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
hypothenuse=10000
thesets=[]
for x in xrange(1, hypothenuse):
    a=math.sqrt(hypothenuse**2-x**2)
    if(int(a)==a):
        thesets.append([x,a])
print "amount of sets: ", len(thesets)
for i in range(len(thesets)):
    print thesets[i][0],thesets[i][1], math.sqrt(thesets[i][0]**2+ thesets[i][1]**2)
```

edit: changed so you can print the sets too, (this method is in O(n), which is the fastest possible method i guess?) note: if you want the amount of sets, each one is given twice, for example: 15**2=9**2+12**2 = 12**2+9**2

Not sure if i understand your code correctly, but if you give in 12, do you than want all possible triangles with hypothenuse smaller than 12? or do you than want to know the possibilities (one as far as i know) to write 12**2=a**2+b**2?

if you want all possibilities, than i will edit the code a little bit

**for all possibilities of a**2+b**2 = c**2, where c< hypothenuse**  (not sure if that is the thing you want):

```
hypothenuse=15
thesets={}
for x in xrange(1,hypothenuse):
    for y in xrange(1,hypothenuse):
        a=math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
        if(a<hypothenuse and int(a)==a):
            if(x<=y):
                thesets[(x,y)]=True
            else:
                thesets[(y,x)]=True
print len(thesets.keys()) 
print thesets.keys()
```

this solves in O(n**2), and your solution does not even work if hypothenuse=15, your solution gives:

(3, 4, 5)
(5, 12, 13)
Number of sets: 2

while correct is: 
3
[(5, 12), (3, 4), (6, 8)]

since 5**2+12**2=13**2, 3**2+4**2=5**2, and 6**2+8**2=10**2, while your method does not give this third option?
edit: changed numpy to math, and my method doesnt give multiples either, i just showed why i get 3 instead of 2, (those 3 different ones are different solutions to the problem, hence all 3 are valid, so your solution to the problem is incomplete?)

Comment: I'm new to programming so I don't understand some parts of your code. What is numpy and what does .sqrt() do? Also, I'm using python 3 so xrange does not work for me. Thanks!

Comment: sqrt == Square Root.  The hypotenuse is equal to the square root of the sum of the sides squared... or H = SQRT( X^2 + Y^2 )

Comment: in python 3.x, range() will do what in 2.x is done by xrange(), but i am using 2.x so i wrote it like that because in 2.x, xrange() is better than range().

Comment: well I am actually looking for all possibilities

Comment: edited it a bit, (does my code give you the result you want for lower numbers?)

Comment: Using numpy to calculate sqrt of an int, seriously? Why do people always rush to numpy for doing things that can be done perfectly with built in features? You know there's a [`math`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sqrt) module in python, right?

Comment: guess it is the force of habit, (i normally never use ints, but always ndarrays, hence the use of numpy)  edit: a -1 for using numpy instead of math??? seriously?

Comment: I'm filtering out all multiples in my solution, which explains why there are only 2 sets

Comment: @usethedeathstar Yes, seriously. Your solution doesn't work on a standard python installation, it forces the user to install an external module, which even has C extensions that need to be compiled. This also means it can't be used in alternative Python implementations like jython or any other nonstandard system. And all this for a feature that is readily available in a standard library function, which is probably even faster for simple ints. Change it to `math` and I'll remove the downvote, but just adding a dependency like this without thinking about it is a very bad thing to do.

Comment: @l4mpi changed the numpy to math, didnt really think about numpy being non-standard, since it has always been one of those i always had, both at home and at work already installed

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick attempt using pre-calculated squares and cached square-roots. There are probably many mathematical optimisations.

```
def find_tri(h_max=10):
  squares = set()
  sq2root = {}
  sq_list = []
  for i in xrange(1,h_max+1):
    sq = i*i
    squares.add(sq)
    sq2root[sq] = i
    sq_list.append(sq)
  #
  tris = []
  for i,v in enumerate(sq_list):
    for x in sq_list[i:]:
      if x+v in squares:
        tris.append((sq2root[v],sq2root[x],sq2root[v+x]))
  return tris
```

Demo:

```
>>> find_tri(20)
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One very easy optimization is to arbitrarily decide `x <= y`. e.g., if `(10,15,x)` is not a solution then `(15,10,x)` will not be a solution either. This also means that if `2x**2 > hypoteneuse**2` then you can terminate the algorithm as there is no solution.